# Mod_Rewrite: Force https besides specific page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an application that requires SSL in a folder called "secure".

So within the "secure" folder of my site in the .htaccess file I'm using the following code to force https:// on that section of the site:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} secure
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/secure/$1 [R,L]
```

How could I modify this so that domain.com/secure/pay/callback would be able to use regular http://

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an exclusion

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} secure
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/secure/pay/callback
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/secure/$1 [R,L]
```

That's a pretty specific case, though; is that enough?